# VBA mysql_num_rows() equivalent

Tags: vba

Guys is there an equivalent value of PHP's  mysql_num_rows() to store a specific query result in array in Visual Basic?

how do we  place the result of Set MyRec = MyDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT TowerUnit From tab") in in array?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read this for the mysql_num_rows()'s equivalent: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821452.aspx

Don't forget to carefully read about using MoveLast if you want an accurate value.

As for your other question, a recordset IS an array.